# Passive summing of two PWM signals

Tags: pwm, dac, passive-networks, resolution

I want to sum/mix 2 PWM signals in order to reach a better resolution on a DAC (see [here](http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/digital/pwm-dac/dual-pwm-circuits/) or [here](http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/PWMDAC)).

I need help to understand the limitations of a simple resistors network to sum my two signals as described in the previous links. Indeed, I succesfully implemented this to sum two 3-bits PWM running at 10kHz as a test and I am now wondering what can be the advantages of summing those signals by using an op amp or by using "complex" circuits like the one described in the second part of the first link.

I understand that with the passive resistor summing, I have to be sure my two PWM signals have the same impedance but it should be the case as they come from the same MCU. I also understand that this method will not give the best results in terms of distorsion but as long as I am not using this to carry audio signals or other sensible signals, it should be okay, right ?

Briefly, I'd like to know your opinion on using passive resistors suming to mix let's say two 8-bits PWM signals at around 10 kHz in order to emulate a 16-bits PWM signal and what can be the pros and cons of using another "sophisticated" method. The resulting signal after filtering has low frequency (<1 kHz) but requires good SNR.

Comment: Is your 8-bit PWM source designed with one part in \$2^{16}\$ accuracy (or precision, depending how you're using it)?

Comment: Start by defining your signal BW , and THD and SNR desired

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, I assume for this example that the source of the PWM is not a problem.

Comment: http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/digital/pwm-dac/pwm-distortion-analysis/  PWM has inherent distortion  YOu are far better off with an I2C DAC or parallel DAC

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 I do not have precise ideas yet of those parameters but the BW might be <1kHz, the SNR has to be quite high, let say over 1000. Once again I only have a rough idea for those parameters right now, are they critical point to consider in order to descriminate one solution or another ? Thank you

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 I know, I'm currently trying to get rid of an existing DAC for economic reasons. The results i obtained with a very coarse PWM are satisfying regarding my application, that is why I do not care much about distorsion and other signal integrity parameters

Comment: THe slope of the filter at 20dB / decade implies with 10k/1kHz you need at least a 3rd order filter, then define either flat group delay , amplitude or linear phase response and 60dB SNR also needs THD -60dB or 0.1%, I would suggest you use u Law DAC with 4~8KHz frame rate

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thank you for this answer. I am indeed using a 4th order RC filter to filter the PWM signal. I am not familiar with this type of DAC, I'll take a look and come back to you ASAP. Thank you again.

Comment: Or cheaper, use a sigma delta DAC  with 4th order Bessel filter

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 DAC appart, do you see any advantages of using op amp summing or the solution with inverters over using a simple resistor network ?

Comment: Yes active filter design tools are trivial for any response you want, high Q, std tolerance and BP, Band reject ratio, I use FilterPRoDT.exe,, Passive RC are worse for group delay

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 What about summing the signals before filtering ? I'm thinking about using the same filtering on whatever summing method is used.

Comment: If you read my link on PWM distortion vs Phase modulation, that will not meet your 60dB SNR criteria due to distortion.  They would have to be filtered then added synchronously . http://www.openmusiclabs.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/pwm_dac_sm.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thank you for your answer. If I increase frequency and if my SNR is less critical, it would then be suitable ?